# how should i interpret boxplot and manova results simultaneously?

Tags: manova, boxplot

I have a data in which i am interested in how the response of photosynthesis and conductance varies differentially among different temperatures/ranks/crosses/genotypes. I have set up a manova to do this and i found that that only conductance is significantly different for the above three factors. I have simultaneously plotted boxplots to try and compare the manova results and i found that the manova and boxplot results are not the same. Am i missing something.

Here are the manova results:

```
>summary.aov(photo_cond.manova)
 Response Photo :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Temp.group    2    267 133.653  0.7611 0.4681
Cross         5    828 165.501  0.9424 0.4538
Rank          1      0   0.498  0.0028 0.9576
Tree.ID       5    298  59.539  0.3390 0.8890
Residuals   296  51981 175.613               

 Response Cond :
             Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Temp.group    2 0.41172 0.205861 20.8793 3.292e-09 ***
Cross         5 1.17285 0.234570 23.7911 < 2.2e-16 ***
Rank          1 0.00655 0.006553  0.6646    0.4156    
Tree.ID       5 0.77387 0.154774 15.6978 1.042e-13 ***
Residuals   296 2.91843 0.009860                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here are the boxplots for photosynthesis and conductance..

[image: photosynthesis]

[image: Conductance]

Comment: This is hard to interpret as presented. Can you clarify your Q (& use proper English punctuation etc)? The plots look like there would be interactions in your data, did you try fitting any interaction terms?

Comment: Remember that box plots don't show means and they don't always show the fine structure of variation very well either. Some of these box plots appear to be based on very small group sizes and/or to be implying many ties in the data. 25% of the values should be beyond each quartile, but the whiskers are often absent or very short. That's puzzling as the other indications imply number of observations is a few hundred.

Comment: Your colour coding implies that you have very, very few observations for temp = 34 (?$^\circ$C). My knowledge of this field is limited to the fact that my brother did his Ph.D. on photosynthesis but do you expect to detect a difference between effects of temperatures of 34 and 35? Orthogonal comment: best not to mix red and green colours. Many biologists, and humans generally, cannot distinguish them.

Comment: @Nick I agree that boxplots doesn't show the fine structure of variation but at least they will tell us the pattern of variation. Right? I expected to see the similar patterns between boxplots and manova results but it isn't the case so. I think temp = 34C might be a typo or special case (which i need to find out soon). I agree that colors need to be changed. Will work on that..

Comment: I'd much rather plot means and every single data point when that is what you comparing. Why not check photosynthesis and conductance separately?

Comment: Note that the box plot is giving you quite different scales for light and dark. That is hiding some heteroscedasticity which usually complicates interpretation. Photosynthesis is clearly positive in the light and negative in the dark, which rules out log transformation, which might otherwise make sense. On the other hand, there is lots of science on this and it's hard to believe you are not stumbling into well-known problems with standard solutions in the biological literature.